# whenever I use "sudo su", i'm getting "bash: export : = not a valid identifier". I'm new to linux. Please excuse for not being more informative

Tags: linux, ubuntu, sudo, ubuntu-20.04, superuser

[image: Screenshot of my terminal]

I'm using UBUNTU 20.04,wayland. However I'm getting root privileges after that two messages.

Comment: Root's `.bashrc` has an `export` line with spaces around the `=`. It should be `export PATH=/...` with no spaces around `=`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The root `.bashrc` file has a line that looks like this:

```
export PATH = /snap/bin:/usr/local/sbin/...
```

Get rid of the spaces around the `=`.

```
export PATH=/snap/bin:/usr/local/sbin/...
```

Comment: Thank You very much. I checked only my profile `.bashrc`. I didn't knew about root `.bashrc`. This solved my problem

Comment: When you use `sudo su`, you're running a shell as root, so it runs root's .bashrc.